# Creating "Tools" in FabricJS?

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs, paperjs

I am working on a simple editor where you can move text, pictures, and pretty much anything around. It's nothing too complicated, however I am having an issue choosing between using PaperJS and FabricJS - The main reason being the ability to natively transform items (rotate, scale, etc.).

Even though I love PaperJS, I am really considering moving to FabricJS. I create tools for PaperJS like this:

```
function shapeTool(options) {
    this.tool = new Tool();
    var options = $.extend({
        shape: "circle",
    }, options);

    this.tool.onMouseUp = function(event) { ... }

    ...
    ...

    this.tool.activate();
    return tool;
}
```

This is probably the worst way to create them, but for me it's easy to throw all these functions in a file and init my tools: `var tool = new shapeTool(options);`

Since I will possibly be moving to Fabric, what is the easiest way to make modular tools. In which I can swap between them? (i.e. I have a toolbar and when i click a button my tool changed so i can freedraw, insert images, etc)

**Clarification:** When I mean a tool, I am talking about a tool in PaperJS. IN Paper, we are able to swap the canvas's active tool. The tool would handle the current mouseDown, KeyDown, etc. events for the canvas. I could write different tools for things like inserting shapes and images, and write one for freedrawing. I could then set the active tool to either one. This would allow me to swap between freedraw and inserting shapes.

Thanks,
Hunter M.

Comment: you mean toolbar? what is a tool?

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi please look at my clarification. Thanks.

Comment: You can transform items in Paper.js, why would you switch to Fabric.js? Paper.js is great

Comment: @arthur.sw I am not looking just to "scale" something. I need a native way to transform an item built in. Look at the homepage of FabricJS. Paper doesn't have a tool to do something as trivial as that.

Comment: and we added more :p you can even skew now.

Comment: I created [romanesco.io](http://romanesco.io/) with paper.js (it's still a WIP), you can select a shape and transform it (I don't handle skew, but I could). I had to develop the interactive bounding box myself, but it's definitely worth it, paper.js rocks in so many ways! (I didn't use Fabric.js, it seems nice as well)

Comment: Paper.js provides tools to work along paths and smooth them, which is extremely handy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In FabricJS you interact with the behaviour of mouse with events.

[Cavas](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html) fires:

- mouse:down
- mouse:move
- mouse:up
- mouse:over
- mouse:out

You register events with **ON** and **OFF**:

```
canvas.on('mouse:down', handler);
```

You have just on predefined state that is drawingMode true or false

```
canvas.isDrawingMode = true;
```

And free drawing starts.

When not drawing the mouse down and up or move can be customized by a property you add to canvs.

```
canvas.myState = 'addStamps';
```

Then in your handler:

```
handler(e) {
  switch (canvas.myState) {
    case 'deleteItems':
      e.target && canvas.remove(e.target);
    break;
    case 'addStamps':
      canvas.add(new fabric.Image('stamp.jpg'));
    break;
  }
}
```

You have to do same for mouse:up or mosue:move if you need interaction other than clicks.

This is one of the many ways you can obtain a similar effect.

Comment: So, for each "tool" I would have to create an "editorState"?

Comment: Should create a flag somewhere where you can switch the behaving of the handler you bind to mouse events. this is an approach.

Comment: a little off-topic. I see you are able to customize the bounds box around the selected object, but its on a per-object basis. Is there a way to set that globally? like `selectionBorderColor`?

Comment: You can do both on Canvas for all objects or on a per object basis. Object box and controls are being changed those days to a more customizable version

Comment: NO there is no support for global controls options. You have to setup it overriding the objectClass. When is time make a question i'll answer, or just try it, it is so simple.